# How to convert array in [1,2,3] format in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working in Laravel and using the orWhereIn() which takes array in [1,2,3,4] format.
This is what i am doing but it convert in string:

```
$group_id=array()
$user_groups=ChatGroupMember::where('group_users_id',$login_user_id)->get();
foreach ($user_groups as $grp) {
    array_push($group_id,$grp->group_id);
}
$groupList = implode(',', $group_id);
dd($groupList);
```

Comment: Just use the `$group_id` array, don't call `implode`.

Comment: $group_id  is giving indexed array which is not accepted by whereIn().

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is an indexed array.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) about `whereIn()`, that's exactly what it accepts: `>whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])` (which is an indexed array).

Comment: yes @MagnusEriksson but $group_id is in 0 => 1 format.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is the same thing as: `[0 => 1, 1 => 2,  2 => 3]`, which is an indexed array. In PHP, there are two types of arrays, indexed (starts with 0 and all keys are in sequence) and associative arrays (where the keys doesn't start with 0, aren't in sequence or aren't numeric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$group_ids` in the `whereIn` is OK.

```
$group_ids=array();
$user_groups=ChatGroupMember::where('group_users_id',$login_user_id)->get();
foreach ($user_groups as $grp) {
    array_push($group_ids,$grp->group_id);
}

...

......whereIn('id', $group_ids); 
// ......whereIn('id', "[" . join(",",$group_ids) . "]");   // if it accept a string rather than an array.
```

Comment: i have done this but when printed last executed query $group_ids values are not showing in query. if i pass hard coded value like [1,2,3] then its showing. So there may be issue of array format.

Comment: If it accept a string, use `......whereIn('id', "[" . join(",",$group_ids) . "]");`

Comment: @AshutoshDubey - Do a `var_dump($group_ids)` after your foreach-loop and check what it actually contains. You can also [see this demo](https://3v4l.org/imliv) to see that an array created with `array_push()` will look the same as the hard coded `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: after doing var_dump() we get :-array(2) { [0]=> int(5001) [1]=> int(5002) }

Comment: @AshutoshDubey the output format is styled by var_dump.

Comment: @AshutoshDubey - That's the same thing as `[5001, 5002]`. If you do a var dump of that hard coded, you will get the same result.